# Django IntegrityError manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement hashtags in my django app
I have a message model with a field like this

```
hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag, related_name='message_hash_tags')
```

And this is the HashTag model

```
    hash_tag = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)
```

And I'm setting the hashtags to the message like this

```
            hash_tags_list = Functions.extract_hashtags(message["message"])
            hash_tags = [HashTag.objects.get_or_create(hash_tag=ht) for ht in hash_tags_list]
            messageObj.hash_tags.set(hash_tags)
            messageObj.save()
```

But this errors out

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "messaging_message_hash_tags" violates foreign key constraint "messaging_message_ha_hashtag_id_068959e9_fk_messaging"
DETAIL:  Key (hashtag_id)=((<HashTag: HashTag object (skills)>, True)) is not present in table "messaging_hashtag".
```

Tho I can find the `HashTag object (skills)` in my `messaging_hashtag` table:

```
SELECT * FROM messaging_hashtag;
 hash_tag 
----------
 skills
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`get_or_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a tuple which contains the object and a flag on whether the object was created or not, so something like: `(obj, created)`

To fix this, just extract the `obj` from the tuple. For example using `[0]` on the result:

```
hash_tags = [ HashTag.objects.get_or_create(hash_tag=ht)[0] for ht in hash_tags_list ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I knew that, I didn't know it was checking after the `,` I considered the check only till here ```<HashTag: HashTag object (skills)>```